# Nivo Slider: slider disappears after last slide and shows up again after 30 seconds or so. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nivo-slider

I'm having a problem with NivoSlider. The whole slider disappears after last slide (I'm using 3 at the moment, but I can change it anytime) and shows up again after 30 seconds or so.

```
<div id="slider-container">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider theme-default">
    <img src="img/slider/slider1.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/slider/slider2.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/slider/slider3.jpg"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect:'fade'
});
});
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

See it live: http://pandartt.com.br/novosite

What am I missing? Couldn't find a fix for it yet.

Thank you,

Giovanna

Comment: Can you please post the relevant bits of HTML and JavaScript here?

Comment: mc10, is this what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `script` and `link` elements outside of `#slider`. Nivoslider thinks that they are slides and is trying to display them as slides number 4, 5, 6 and 7.

Currently your markup looks like this:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider theme-default">
    <img src="img/slider/slider1.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/slider/slider2.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/slider/slider3.jpg"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                           
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect:'fade'
        });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

See how the `link` and `script` elements are nested inside the `#slider` div? Changing the markup to this should do the trick:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider theme-default">
    <img src="img/slider/slider1.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/slider/slider2.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/slider/slider3.jpg"/>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                           
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect:'fade'
    });
    });
</script>
```

Even better, move the links to your stylesheets to the `head` of the document, and move your scripts either to the `head` of the document, or just before the closing `body` tag.